# Find all points $(a,b,c)$ where the graph $z = f(x,y)$ has a horizontal tangent plane.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Given $f(x,y)=x^2 + 4xy + y^2 - 2x + 2y + 1$

I tried setting $F(x,y,z) = f(x,y) - z$ and found the partial derivatives Fx, Fy, and Fz.

Fx = 2x + 4y -2

Fy = 4x + 2y + 2

Fz = -1

Apparently the gradient  is perpendicular to the tangent plane, so it must be parallel to <0,0,1> which the normal vector of the xy plane. So I set Fx = 0 and Fy = 0 and solved for x and y, which turns out to be -1 and 1 respectively. But I don't know where to go from here, or whether what I have done so far is correct at all. Please help.

Comment: That’s it. You’re done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(x,y)$ has a horizontal tangent plane, that means $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0.$$  So you calculate each partial derivative, and solve for when both are simultaneously zero.  Then plug in those coordinates into $f$ to get the $z$-value.

Comment: Thank you so much.